# Using apply between two unequal length in rows

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am doing eda on a two movie dataframes. What I want to do is transfer the text values in the title_cast column in the imdb_df dataframe to the new title_cast column in the movie_df dataframe. The condition for the transfer is based on the movieId in both dataframes. But I have a problem. The movieId column in the movie_df dataframe is longer than the imdb_df dataframe. That means, when I am calling apply on the movie_df dataframe, some rows are not in the imdb_df. Therefore, it does not return any result. So pandas is throwing an error on those instances. I really don't know what to do. Let me show it in pictures.

For example, this is the movie_df dataframe

| movieId | genre |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Youth |
| 002 | Adult |
| 003 | Fantasy |
| 004 | Animation |

But the imdb_df dataframe is structured this way

| movieId | title_cast |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Tom Hanks, Allen |
| 002 | Goldberg, Tom Hanks |

Then, I want to transfer the title_cast column values in imdb_df to movie_df using this functions and calls:

```
def add_title_cast(x):
    # create a series of the movieid column in imdb df
    title_series = imdb_df['movieId']
    # check if the movieId from the movies df is in the series
    if x in title_series.values:
        title_case = imdb_df[imdb_df['movieId'] == x]['title_cast']
        return title_case
    else:
        return " "         

movies_df['title_cast'] = movies_df['movieId'].apply(add_title_cast)
```

When I run the above code, pandas gives me an error. I guess it is where the movieId in movie_df doesn't have a corresponding entry in imdb_df movieId column.

The specific error the above function calls give is:
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'get_indexer'

I have searched all over the Internet for a solution but could not find one. Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: Could you add the tracelog of the error? It would be much easier to answer you. thanks

Comment: error notification added. thanks

Comment: Why aren't you just doing a merge?

Comment: Any reason why you are not just joining two dataframes instead of using the function you provided?

Comment: I really didn't know I could do a merge or join both dataframes. I will look into that. Just new to pandas.

Answer (score 1):

`imdb_df[imdb_df['movieId'] == x]['title_cast']` returns a Series, you may need get the first value from it

```py
title_case = imdb_df.loc[imdb_df['movieId'] == x, 'title_cast'].item()
# or
title_case = imdb_df.loc[imdb_df['movieId'] == x, 'title_cast'].iloc[0]
# or convert Series value to list
title_case = imdb_df.loc[imdb_df['movieId'] == x, 'title_cast'].tolist()
```

You can also try `merge`

```py
movies_df['title_cast'] = movies_df.merge(imdb_df, on=['movieId'], how='left')['title_cast']
```

Comment: thanks. this worked perfectly. But will still research on doing a merge. I think merges would be even nice. Thanks @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @emekadavid Updated the answer with `merge`

Comment: that was nice of you @Ynjxsjmh. Now I can merge all the columns together. Thanks. Appreciate your kindness.